# Amazon Redshift Sum window function on group

Tags: sql, select, sum, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to use the sum window function to get the following results in green

[image]

I can get the total by using the following, but its givings a runnning total, I am looking for a group total

```
sum(groupvolume) OVER ( PARTITION BY geo_group  ORDER BY Month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS group_volume
```

Comment: perfect thanks works a treat

Answer (score 2):

Just drop the `rows between` clause. By default, it will apply the function to all the rows within the partition. Note that without the `rows` clause, the `order by` clause is also meaningless:

```
SUM(groupvolume) OVER (PARTITION BY geo_group) AS group_volume
```